Cancel button is not showing in the NETMaui
I'm using a SearchBar and looking at the documentation it contains a "cancel" button and a SearchCommand but I couldn't find the use.
//Documentation search bar docs

<Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" StrokeThickness="1">
    <SearchBar BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
               CancelButtonColor="Black"
               Placeholder="Tasks and more"
               SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
</Border>

//my visual

I would like the cancel button to be displayed

As stated in the documentation, I believe the Cancel button next to the cross mark in the search bar is an IOS feature. Search bar on Android devices simply shows a Cross. If you wish to, you can explicitly add a Cancel button next to the search bar for android.

You can refer to the official doc to get more details about Border.

You can use the following code to achieve the effect you want:
Page.xaml:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             Title="MainPage"
             Padding="5">

   <HorizontalStackLayout  Spacing="10" BackgroundColor="LightGrey"
                           Padding="10"
                           WidthRequest="380"
                           HeightRequest="50"
                           VerticalOptions="Start">
        <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 14,14,14,14" StrokeThickness="1" 
                WidthRequest="300" 
                HeightRequest="40">
            <SearchBar BackgroundColor="White" CancelButtonColor="Black"
                       Placeholder="Tasks and more"
                       x:Name="searchbar"/>
        </Border>

        <Label Text="Cancel"  
           TextColor="Grey"
           FontSize="Body"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>

Page.xaml.cs:
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


   private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        searchbar.Unfocus();
    }
}

When you click "Cancel", it will make SeachBar Unfocused(hide soft keyboard).
Update:
If you want to use Grid, check this:
<Grid Margin="10"
          BackgroundColor="LightGrey"
          WidthRequest="380"
          HeightRequest="50"
          VerticalOptions="Start">
    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <Border Grid.Column="0"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 14,14,14,14" StrokeThickness="1"
            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="40">
        <SearchBar BackgroundColor="White"
                   CancelButtonColor="Black"
                    Placeholder="Tasks and more"
                    x:Name="searchbar"/>
    </Border>
    
    <Label Grid.Column="1"
           Text="Cancel" TextColor="Grey"
           FontSize="Body"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
</Grid>

Here is the effect. The first one is using Grid, the second one is using HorizontalStackLayout.

The Border should be around the HorizontalStackLayout, otherwise, the Cancel button or label will be outside of the Border with the rounded corners. I would also use a Grid instead of a HorizontalStackLayout for this.

Indeed, I edited the answer.

I would still place the Border around everything, even the Grid.
